# Excel VBA macro Update SQL Statement via OracleInProcServer Connection

Tags: excel, vba, oracle

I am trying to update an Oracle table from a vba marco with the OraSession = CreateObject("OracleInProcServer.XOraSession") and then OraDatabase Object. I am able to Insert and Select data but I haven't found a working Update statement.

```
    Set OraSession = CreateObject("OracleInProcServer.XOraSession")
    Set OraDatabase = OraSession.DbOpenDatabase("xxxx", "xxx/xxx", 0&)
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sample Request Form")
    eln_ref = ws1.Cells(7, 3).value
    expd = ws1.Cells(2, 3).value
    exp_date = Format(expd, "dd-mmm-yy")
    str = " Update Table SET EXP_DATE = '" & exp_date & "' WHERE EXP_ID = '" & eln_ref & "'"
    OraDatabase.Executesql (str)
```

I have taken the string and ran it in sql developer and it operates the update. But it does update but also doesn't error when executed through excel. I have also tried using the CreateSQL method but then the .Executesql method doesn't accept its output.

Oracle Database Object information:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e17727/serobjch010.htm#OOFOL380

Any Ideas?

Comment: Off topic, but you should not have literals as parameters in your sql.  use proper bind parameters.

Comment: What are proper bind parameters? Literals are my constants between ' ' right? @OldProgrammer

Comment: The link you provided for ExecuteSQL method documentation explains it with an example.

Comment: Do you mean the .BeginTrans & .CommitTrans? I added those with no change. but thanks for the tip.